# Indexing a scripting language in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am writing an Eclipse plugin for a 2D game engine (<http://www.ksatechnologyhq.com:1357/>) that has its own scripting language. I want to index all scripts in AIGE projects, so I can fill content assist lists with functions from other files (like Eclipse does with Java). How is this done?

(By the way, [here](http://www.ksatechnologyhq.com:1357/pwlib/PWLib_in_a_Nutshell.pdf) is the only documentation on the syntax on said language and the extensions I want to use are AHLSL and HLSL.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a DSL (Domain Specific Language) that has no tooling and that you would like to provide an editor for, consider using [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/).  You need to provide a grammar file for your DSL, and XText generates an eclipse editor with hooks for providing Syntax Highlighting, Code Completion, Validation, quick fixes, etc.

See [Getting Started](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/latest/xtext.html#getting-started) for a mini-tutorial on turning a DSL to a grammar.

Answer (score 0):

UA (like Help) uses Apache Lucene to index all of its content to allow for searches.  Aside from looking at the org.eclipse.help code, see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene and http://darksleep.com/lucene/.  Eclipse SDK ships with 3 org.apache.lucene bundles.

AFAIK JDT maintains an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) model.  The editor keeps its model up to date, and so at any given point has access to, say, all the methods that can be called for that object.  If I find out more I'll add an edit.

PW

Comment: AIGE uses its own scripting language which is NOTHING like Java. Any advice on using it for said language?

Comment: Using lucene?  You would build indices of your source with it and your script language model would need to bridge to that.  Regardless of what you do, you would need to build your own model of your scripting language.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/The_Official_Eclipse_FAQs#Implementing_Support_for_Your_Own_Language for an overview.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the DOM. The wiki didn't tell me much about actually making it and references examples which don't exist.